# Publishing an Angular application with Netlify (The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation at Function.getCompilationHooks)

Tags: angular, webpack, netlify

I am using: node --version `v14.15.4`

`MONGO_URL` and `JWT_SECRET` Config Variables

I made an Angular application trying to publish in `Netlify` but I am getting this error:

```
Ng build --prod
⠋ Generating browser application bundles...
An error occurred during the build:
TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
    at Function.getCompilationHooks
 (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:114:10)
    at C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:566:67
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:99:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:631:26)
    at C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:667:29
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:662:28)
    at C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:321:11
    at Compiler.readRecords (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:529:11)
    at C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:318:10
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\les\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\builbuild-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lik\lib\Compiler.js:315:19
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\AutoLogon\Desktop\web422-FinalAss6\web422FinalAss6\node_modules\les\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
An unhandled exception occurred: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
See "C:\Users\AutoLogon\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-9JPp0X\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was an issue with `"aot":true` in the angular.json file. Try turning aot off.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your webpack package

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@netlify-builder/deploy) just run `ng add @netlify-builder/deploy` in your repo and run through the setup. I use netlify with angular routinely and this is my workflow. Deploys will then be as simple as `ng deploy` although you might have to manually publish on the netlify interface depending on your settings.

[here's the official guide from netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/09/17/using-the-angular-builder-for-netlify/)